Calculation of intersection multiplicity after the restricting to a fiber
Let $X\to\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z$ be an arithmetic surface which is projective, regular and integral. Let $D$ and $E$ two divisors intersecting  at a point $x\in X$ that lies over the prime $p$. I wonder if I can calculate the intersection multiplicity at $x$  (in symbols $i_x(D,E)$) just by looking at the local ring $\mathcal O_{X_p,x}$.
Specifically: let $d_x, e_x\in\mathcal O_{X,x}$ the local equations of $D$ and $E$ at $x$, respectively. Then the reduction modulo $p$ gives the map $\mathcal O_{X,x}\to \mathcal O_{X_p,x}$. I would like to know if the following equality holds:
$$
i_x(D,E)=\operatorname{length}_{\mathcal O_{X_p,x}}\mathcal O_{X_p,x}/(\overline d_x, \overline e_x)
$$
where $\overline d_x$, $\overline e_x$ are the obvious images of $d_x$, $e_x$.

That is not true.  Let $X$ be Proj of $\mathbb{Z}[s,t]$.  Let $D$ be the divisor of $t$.  Let $E$ be the divisor if $t-p^{m}s$.  The intersection multiplicity equals $m$, but the integer you compute equals $1$.
